# g++ gives error: ‘node* link’ redeclared as different kind of symbol

Tags: c++, g++

This code compiles and runs fine in Codelite IDE on my windows machine (using g++.exe):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct node {
    int i;
    node* next;
    node(int x, node* t) {
        i = x;
        next = t;
    }
};


node *link;

int main()
{
    cout << "Yes!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the same code, when compiled on a Linux machine with g++ gives the following error.

```
simpleTest.cpp:16: error: ‘node* link’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/usr/include/unistd.h:809: error: previous declaration of ‘int link(const char*, const char*)’
```

What could be the reason for it to compile and run fine on Windows side but give compilation errors on Linux side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> What could be the reason for it to compile and run fine on Windows
>   side but give compilation errors on Linux side?

On Linux, [`link()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/link.html) is already declared as a function inside `unistd.h`:

```
int link(const char *path1, const char *path2);
```

On Windows, `link()` doesn't exist.

If you want your code to compile on both platforms, use a different name for your `node*` variable.

Comment: FYI, `link()` doesn't exist on Windows, which is why the code compiles on Windows.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes. updated my post to clarify the problem in Linux. thanks!